# How to deserialize JSON with fixed type header and variant type body in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization

My json string including a fixed type header and non-fixed type body as bellow:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponseHeader
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public ServiceResponseHeader Header { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Body { get; set; }
}
```

At runtime, I can get the type of Body from configuration file, but how can I desterilize the json to the object specified type through DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject() ?

The sample code:

```
string json = @"{ "Header": {"ErrorCode":"0000", "Message":"Got Profile Successfully"}, "Body": [{"DisplayName":"Mike Code","PictureUrl":null,"Title":"Manager"}] }"

Type objType = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.MyTypeName");  //Get Type from configuration file

ServiceResponse obj = new ServiceResponse ()
{
    Header = new ServiceResponseHeader(),
    Body = Activator.CreateInstance(objType)
};

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    ServiceResponse returnObj = (ServiceResponse)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Here I can get Header(returnObj.Header.Message) properly, but returnObj.Body is not the type of MyAssembly.MyTypeName and I cannot get it's properties.

Any suggestions for solving such issue?

Comment: try "dynamic" if your are using .net 4.0

Comment: this may help if body is different types of objects that can be determined by something in the header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net/12727186#12727186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still cannot find any solution via DataContractJsonSerializer, I have to use JSON.NET to solve  this issues, the sample code is as below:

```
    public static dynamic[] Deserialize(Type headerType, Type bodyType, string json)
    {
        var root = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

        dynamic header = serializer.Deserialize(root["Header"].CreateReader(),headerType);
        dynamic body = serializer.Deserialize(root["Body"].CreateReader(), bodyType);

        return new dynamic[] { header, body };
    }
```

The headerType is known, the bodyType can be loaded from configuration file (Type bodyType = Type.GetType(configClassName)), this public method will return Header and Body object, then I can convert them into the objects of given types that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to solve this problem by using an interface instead of object, and making use of the "specify known types" version of the DataContractJsonSerializer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209.aspx ) ?

It would look something like

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IMySerializable), new [] {
                                                   typeof(ConcreteSerializable1),
                                                   typeof(ConcreteSerializable2)
                                              });
```

Basically, DataContractSerializer needs context on what you expect it might serialize/deserialize, it can't infer types from the content of the JSON.  If you don't want to do that you may want to consider a third party library that will give you more freedom to interpret the JSON as you please.  Or the JavaScriptSerializer, but it is slow compared to some third party libraries.

Comment: I am using the following code to test and still cannot deserialize the body the type (ProfileItem) that I specified :

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TransactionResponse), new[] {
                                                   typeof(TransactionResponseHeader),
                                                   typeof(ProfileItem)
                                              });

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                var obj = (TransactionResponse)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the JSON.NET library and don't have any experience using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, so I'll answer in terms of JSON.NET. Hopefully you'll be able to translate to the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

---

If you define classes like this:

```
public class MessageHeader
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public MessageHeader Header { get; set; }
    public JToken Body { get; set; }
}
```

You can use them like this:

```
var message = JToken.Parse("...").ToObject<Message>();

if (message.Header.TypeName == "User")
{
    var user = message.Body.ToObject<User>();
}
else if (message.Header.TypeName == "Answer")
{
    var answer = message.Body.ToObject<Answer>();
}
```

where the `User` and `Answer` classes might look something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public bool IsSolution { get; set;}
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

This will let you handle both this message:

```
{
    "Header": { "TypeName": "User" },
    "Body": { "Name": "John Smith", "Email": "jsmith@live.com" }
}
```

and this message:

```
{
    "Header": { "TypeName": "Answer" },
    "Body" : { "IsSolution": true, "Content": "abc" }
}
```