# Control the destination type of the object in an array when deserializing with JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

There is a JSON array like below

```
[{ "name" : "XX", "age" : 20}, { "company" : "YY", "post" : "XXX"} , ...]
```

I want to deserialize it into `object[]`, but I wanna control the actual type of the element in the array to be instance of specificed classes

```
class A{
  public string name;
  public int age;
}

class B{
  public string company;
  public string post;
}
```

So that I can get the object by `(A)array[0]` or `(B)array(1)`

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing heterogenous JSON array into covariant List<> using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in this way

```
using( StringReader sr = new StringReader(json))
using( JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr) )
{
    JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);

    array[0].ToObject<A>();
    array[1].ToObject<B>();
}
```