# Using JSON.NET to deserialize to a derived class

Tags: c#, json, derived-class, json-deserialization

I have been battling with this for few hours and I can't figure out a solution.
Using JSON.NET, I'm trying to deserialize some data to one or another derived class, BUT I want to target the right derived class based on a field that actually is in those data...

Here is a simplified example :

```
public class BaseFile {
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class Directory : BaseFile {
    public int FileSize {get;set;}
}

public class Video : BaseFile {
    public int  Duration{get;set}
}
```

I receive those JSON formatted data :

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "content_type": "application/x-directory", 
      "size": 566686478
    }, 
    {
      "content_type": "video/x-matroska", 
      "duration": 50
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use JSON.NET, based on the `content_type` field, to instantiate either a `Directory` object (if the `content_type` is `application/x-directory`) or a `Video` object (if the `content_type` is `video/x-matroska`).

The simple solution is to deserialize all the content to the base class, and then transform those into their respective derived classes, but I don't find this effective so I'm wondering if there's another solution out there !

Thank you in advance for your input(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed me this post that solves my problem :

[Deserializing heterogenous JSON array into covariant List<> using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net)

I just tried it and for my case, the adapted code is written like this :

```
private BaseFile Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
{
    var type = (string)jObject.Property("content_type");
    switch (type)
    {
        case "application/x-directory":
            return new Directory();
        case "video/x-matroska":
            return new Video();
        default:
            return new BaseFile();
    }
}
```