# How would I deserialize an array like this?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I can't quite seem to work out how I would deserialize this specific array in c# (from a string!) to a class

```
  [
    [
      "PrimaryContact", 
      "=", 
      "Amy R"
    ], 
    "and", 
    [
      "SecondaryContact", 
      "=", 
      "Steven G"
    ],
    "and",
    [
      "ThirdContact",
      "=",
      "Rachel S"
    ]
  ]
```

Specifically it's the middle section that is throwing me, in this case it is "and". It isn't always just three objects, there could an unlimited amount of objects, with an "and" inbetween each of them.

Comment: Is telling whoever wrote the JSON document to grow a brain an option?

Comment: Considering it's DevExpress, that might not be an option.

Comment: Is it _always_ "and"?  Would you consider just stripping all instances of `"and",` from the string?

Comment: @JamesThorpe There is a possibility it could be `"or",`, i've got no idea what dev express is doing here. Might go to them.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net) may provide some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deserialize it into a list of objects:

```
List<object> items = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<object>>(json);
```

Now every other object will be an `Object[]` (containing objects that are `String`), the ones in between `String`.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Bit of a hacky solution so I might go to DevExpress to ask them to 'grow a brain' courtesy of @dcastro!

Answer (score 1):

Using Json.NET, parse everything into a `JArray`, then filter out tokens at even indexes, and then convert each into a `List<string>`.

You'll end up with a collection of `List<string>`, where each list contains 3 elements, e.g., `"PrimaryContact"`, `"="` and `"Amy R"`

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);

IEnumerable<List<string>> result = array.Where((token, index) => index%2 == 0)
                                        .Select(token => token.ToObject<List<string>>());
```

This worked for me using your input

Comment: This removes the `"and"` keyword, which is essential. There are other instances where this keyword *could* be `"or"`

Comment: I thought you didn't need it.. So whats the type of the object you want to end up with? It seems like you want a `List<object>` as suggested by @Guffa then