# How to convert each object in List<ExpandoObject> into its own type?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamic

I have a variable **`inputs`** defined as **`List<ExpandoObject>`**

This was a result of de-serialization of jsonList, which is a JSON array of objects of different structures:

```
dynamic inputs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jsonList, converter);
```

Looping through them I can get a target type of each object, because they all contain a property **`Type`** that has a **`ClassName`** of a target object.

```
foreach (dynamic input in inputs)
{
    // Inside that loop I can get the type
    var inputType = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", input.Type));
    // WCFService is a namespace
    // How can I convert here dynamic **input** object 
    // into an object of type inputType ??
}
```

Basically I want inside that loop convert **input** object into corresponding type specified as string in **input.Type**

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Inside that for-each loop I want to do something like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
Type T = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", input.Type));
T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(T)>(json); // this line fails compilation
```

This way obj will be a strongly-typed object.
I use json serialization in order to do deserialization back, this way all json properies will be replicated into strongly-typed obj automatically.
But the above code doesnt compile, complaining on T for the last line:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

**EDIT2**

Just FYI, the incoming jsonList has this structure, each object in that array can have different properties, except of Name and Type:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "PLAN-A",
        "Type": "CalcInputTypes1",
        "CS": 1.1111,
        "CUSTOM_DATE1": "2015-05-22",
        "CUSTOM_EARN1": 65500.0,
        "GENDER": "Male"
    },
    {
        "Name": "PLAN-B",
        "Type": "CalcInputTypes2",
        "CS": 2.22222,
        "CUSTOM_DATE2": "2015-05-23",
        "CUSTOM_EARN2": 12000.0,
        "PROVINCE": "Ontario"
    }
]
```

CalcInputTypes1, CalcInputTypes2 and most likely CalcInputTypes3,4,5... are the types of such objects in that array...

**SOLUTION**

Thanks guys for your help, especially for suggesting using JObject instead of ExpandoObject, that made the solution much easier and simpler: 
Note:  "thing" will never work, since T in this case must be known at compile time, but I neet to determine type at runtime, so the solution will be like that:

```
    public CalcOutputTypes Calculate2(string jsonList)
    {
        var jobjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(jsonList);

        foreach (var jobject in jobjects)
        {
            Type runtimeType = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", jobject.GetValue("TYPE")));

            var input = jobject.ToObject(runtimeType); // Here we convert JObject to the defined type that just created runtime

            // At this moment you have a strongly typed object "input" (CalcInputTypes1 or CalcInputTypes2 or...)

        }

        return new CalcOutputTypes() { STATUS = "Everything is OK !! (input was: json array of heterogeneous objects)" }; // HERE YOU RETURN CalcOutputTypes OBJECT 
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some simple way that allows easy and effective mapping of properties, but if there is not, then you can just do it manually with a bit of reflection - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/mapping-expandoobject-to-another-object-type.

Comment: What do you then want to do with the type having determined and converted it? Is there a fixed set of types within the list, or is it flexible and dynamic?

Comment: @Amy, will Automapper really work in this case? I thought automapper mapped from one concrete type to another, so I'm unclear how it could work with a dynamic input. If it will work, then post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Eugene, you are correct, this can be done manually by looping through properties, but I am looking an a more generic way, like single-command de-serialization.

Comment: Re-serialize each specific `ExpandoObject` to json, then convert that JSON to the appropriate CLR type using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)

Comment: @David, all object inside List<ExpandoObject> will be casted to corresponding strongly-typed objects. I just need to do all that in runtime, get target class name from input.Type as string, and then do the casting.

Comment: Or, don't use `ExpandoObject`.  Load to an array of `JObject`, and for each `JObject`, check and remove the type property, then do [`obj.ToObject(type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm).

Comment: I added more details to get a better picture...

Comment: @dbc, how do I do that ??

Comment: possibly duplication of [Deserializing heterogenous JSON array into covariant List<> using JSON.NET][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net

Comment: @monstro - see answer (with a small fix I just made).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base/44662567

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using `ExpandoObject` and instead use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) directly, like so:

```
        var query = from obj in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(jsonList, converter)
                    let jType = obj["Type"]
                    where jType != null
                    let type = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", (string)jType))
                    where type != null
                    where obj.Remove("Type") // Assuming this is a synthetic property added during serialization that you want to remove.
                    select obj.ToObject(type);
        var objs = query.ToList();
```

If you need to pass that `converter` down to each specific `ToObject()` call, you can do:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(converter);
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

        var query = from obj in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(jsonList, settings)
                    let jType = obj["Type"]
                    where jType != null
                    let type = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", (string)jType))
                    where type != null
                    where obj.Remove("Type") // Assuming this is a synthetic property added during serialization that you want to remove.
                    select obj.ToObject(type, serializer);
        var objs = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be as @dbc suggested in a comment to use the Newtonsoft.Json method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type)` like this:

```
private T convertTo<T>(string json)
{
    return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(T));
}

var json = // some serialized json ...
var o = convertTo<MyCustomType>(json);
```

where `MyCustomType` is the type from your input (`var inputType = Type.GetType(string.Format("WCFService.{0}", input.Type));`.

Don't forget the implicit cast `(T)`!

Another possibility is to write your own type converter using the .NET framework build-in [TypeConverter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need list of ExpandoObjext's, just use CustomCreationConverter like described in [Deserializing heterogenous JSON array into covariant List<> using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241392/deserializing-heterogenous-json-array-into-covariant-list-using-json-net) so all credits to @JimSan

```
public class Example
{

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var json =
            "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"Name\": \"PLAN-A\",\r\n        \"Type\": \"CalcInputTypes1\",\r\n        \"CS\": 1.1111,\r\n        \"CUSTOM_DATE1\": \"2015-05-22\",\r\n        \"CUSTOM_EARN1\": 65500.0,\r\n        \"GENDER\": \"Male\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n        \"Name\": \"PLAN-B\",\r\n        \"Type\": \"CalcInputTypes2\",\r\n        \"CS\": 2.22222,\r\n        \"CUSTOM_DATE2\": \"2015-05-23\",\r\n        \"CUSTOM_EARN2\": 12000.0,\r\n        \"PROVINCE\": \"Ontario\"\r\n    }\r\n]";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json, new JsonItemConverter());

        Assert.That(result[0], Is.TypeOf<CalcInputTypes1>());
        Assert.That(((CalcInputTypes1)result[0]).Gender, Is.EqualTo("Male"));

        Assert.That(result[1], Is.TypeOf<CalcInputTypes2>());
        Assert.That(((CalcInputTypes2)result[1]).Province, Is.EqualTo("Ontario"));
    }

    public class JsonItemConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<Item>
    {
        public override Item Create(Type objectType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Item Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
        {
            var type = (string)jObject.Property("Type");
            switch (type)
            {
                case "CalcInputTypes1":
                    return new CalcInputTypes1();
                case "CalcInputTypes2":
                    return new CalcInputTypes2();
            }

            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("The given type {0} is not supported!", type));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // Load JObject from stream
            var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

            // Create target object based on JObject
            var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

            // Populate the object properties
            serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

            return target;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Item
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalcInputTypes1 : Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("GENDER")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalcInputTypes2 : Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("PROVINCE")]
        public string Province { get; set; }
    }
}
```