# deserialize json string depending on type

Tags: c#, json.net

Having json strings like this (I have no control over the publisher):

```
{
  "TypeName": "Type1"
}

{
  "TypeName": "Type1"
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to deserialize the json strings dynamically?:

```
public class DeserializationFactory
{
    public static IPoco GetEvent(string jsonString)
    {
        var o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        IPoco poco = null;
        switch (o["TypeName"].ToString())
        {
        case "Type1":
            poco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type1>(jsonString);
            break;

        case "Type2":
            poco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type2>(jsonString);
            break;
        }
        return poco;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you aren't sure which Poco you should deserialize to?

Comment: Not really. It depends on the value of "TypeName"

Comment: You might want to do it with a `JsonConverter` in case your `IPoco` gets included in some higher level object.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648/json-net-serialization-of-type-with-polymorphic-child-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [JsonSubtypes](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes/blob/master/JsonSubTypes/JsonSubtypes.cs) converter implementation and this layout:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "TypeName")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Type1), "Type1")]
    [JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Type2), "Type2")]
    public interface IPoco
    {
        string TypeName { get; }
    }

    public class Type1 : IPoco
    {
        public string TypeName { get; } = "Type1";
        /* ... */
    }

    public class Type2 : IPoco
    {
        public string TypeName { get; } = "Type2";
        /* ... */
    }
```